# PHP readfile error

Tags: php, readfile

I am getting an error. I am trying to read an attachment. It does work perfectly on most files but on few I get this error. The files have the same format and the location it is trying to read from is correct. I have tested it on windows explorer. This is way i am reading it:

```
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename .'"'); 
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
        header('Expires: 0'); 
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 
        header('Pragma: public'); 
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($attachment_location)); 
        ob_clean(); 
        flush(); 
        readfile($attachment_location);     
        exit();
```

This is the error I get

Warning: `readfile(C:\Users\Public\asdgasd\4sf3\Suppliers\saf342\Files\Revit\2016\Seinätikas.rfa): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\downloadattachment.php on line 58`

Comment: It clearly says that there is no such file in your filesystem. Check it out before calling readfile() if such file exists.

Comment: I did check it and it does exist.

Comment: No, I meant you to do something like this: var_dump(file_exists($attachment_location));
This will tell you whether php sees this file or not.

Comment: the response is: bool(false)
So php does not see it.

Comment: Umlauts, Windows and PHP? Deadly combination. :)

Comment: Are you sure the file is readable by your web server (so readable by php script) ?

Comment: Turns out it is what johndodo said. it is the umlauts. php seems not to be able to recognize them. any workaround to that?

Comment: Rename the folder ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Johndodo kind of references, you need to ensure that PHP is operating with the correct internal character set and encoding, so that it recognises the way the file is stored in your (windows) directory structure. See what [character set your windows system is using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then use that same character set for [PHP internal encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php).

**Edit:**

Logic process would be to:

- Open file reference from email and [convert the filename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) `$var` into the correct encoding.
- Do the `file_exists` check
- Proceed to pass the `$var` to the `readfile` function to open.

Answer (score 1):

You should put a checker for see if the file exists in your filesystem.

```
if (!file_exists($filePath)) {

    // Throw an exception or do something for alert the wrong path.
    throw new Exception('File with this path is not available.');

} else {

    // Do your amazing stuff here

}
```

Comment: If you read the comments to the question you will see that OP has already done this.

Answer (score 0):

could you please provide the content of $filename and $attachment_location.

Could you please extend your code with this:

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
 Your code goes here
 ....
 exit();
}
```

Further things to check: Is the file readable by the webserver user (if you're using a websever). 
Does the problem have an effect on files in which there are special chars in the filename ?